# Fedora Firewall no option as of yet

Tags: fedora, iptables, firewall

I need a firewall. 
GUFW a simple firewall was a good option but isnt available on Fedora nor any gui firewall. 
I checked Vuurmuur its powerful but for noobs & if configured wrongly its a great mess (even their documentation forewarns that). Similarly SeLinux is not a firewall

> A firewall controls the flow of traffic to and from a computer to the
>   network. SELinux can confine access of programs within a computer and
>   hence can be conceptually thought of a internal firewall between
>   programs

I think its just a way to protect **core filesystem** nothing more than that ...
So what are my options, please suggest me something some resource that is understandable to a starter & if somehow bugged willn't have **irreversible** consequences.

Further just tell me if I want to reject in/out traffic for the address(s) containing keyword *wolfram* e.g pk.server.wolfram or wolfram-mathematica.com how would I do that in iptables or somehow...& if I want to block intenet for application /opt/telepath-gabble how would I achieve that

Comment: [ufw](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) is very simple to use and has good documentation...

Comment: `selinux` is not about the core filesystem (what ever this is) but about providing acls for application, i.e. this application can connect to the internet or open a specific port, read the filesystem etc.

Comment: selinux is `internal firewall` according to official page how come I control (via selinux) any app's access to net

Comment: @nightcrawler, SELinux is _not_ a firewall. It's a mechanism for managing MAC (Mandatory Access Control, a way of setting up policies that are  more detailed and which override user set permissions).

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with the basic configuration, your Fedora firewall defaults to "on" in a basic GUFW way.

Comment: but how do I configure to block a program or unblock it?

Comment: @nightcrawler I would suggest you read http://www.netfilter.org/ and http://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page to get a good grasp on the capabilities of netfilter and selinux. Then try back and ask for help with specifics

Comment: The Fedora firewall by default has most incomming traffic blocked.